# How to query SharePoint list by external filed name using OData API?

Tags: sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-online

I need to query a SharePoint (Online) list using the OData REST API with specifying an "external" filed name (the one visible to users) in the query.
When I'm specifying the external name in the query, the API returns the error 400 "<attribute> does not exist.".
The same query with the "internal" SharePoint field name works fine.

Here is the example of the query:
In this example the external field name  is "Incident ID" and the internal one for the same field is "Title"

```
... ?\$select='Incident ID',...
```

the above does not work

```
... ?\$select=Title,...
```

and this one works fine.

I've tried as well with using the Incident_x0020_ID, IncidentID but got the same error.
I suspect that it could be some additinal query parameter that would allow "external" names in a query but cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: Could you share the whole endpoint, not only query parameters?

Comment: GET /sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/Items?$select=Incident%20ID,Status&$top=300

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check which fields you have with `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/Items?$select=*` And you will see your field something like `Incident%20ID` or `Incident__ID` then just copy whatever you see to your select query.
I hope this helps.

Comment: The query returns internal fields  names, not the external ones. I.e. Title.

Comment: Sorry my bad, misunderstand at first read. You can't directly select based on external title. But you can expand some fields to see which external names you have and based on those values you can filter. And then you need to write some script to store selected values inside an array. Then you can select inside from that array.

Here is an example for an internal and external values shown in rest api.

`/Items?$expand=FieldValuesAsHtml,FieldValuesAsText,ContentType,ContentType/Fields`